# Silently passing an .nsi file to the cmd as an argument, execute it and create an .exe

Tags: c#, .net, nsis

I am working on an NSIS installer (windows forms application).

The main idea of the application - user goes through a windows forms application, configures all the needed settings and when he/she clicks on "finish" an .nsis file gets generated automatically. makeNSIS.exe is also **included** in my application, so that a user does not have to install it in order to use my installer.

My goal is to silently produce a setup.exe file. I want to pass my automatically generated .nsi file as an argument to the makeNSIS.exe per cmd, tell it to execute it and create a setup.exe file at a certain path. And I want teh whole thing done silently.

One of my failed trials:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //my automatically generated nsis file
        psi.Arguments = Application.StartupPath + "\\NSIS\\NSIS SG Project\\NSIS\\My application.nsi";
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        //nsis application that is included in my project so that users wouldn't have to install it
        psi.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\NSIS\\makeNSIS.exe";
        Process.Start(psi);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And if you don't hide the window, does the output have any errors? Process exit code?

Comment: It says it was successful, but I see no generated exe file anywhere. Even if I directly enter "makensis.exe mynsisfile.nsi" in the cmd, it executes everything successfully, but no exe file is to be seen. What could it be?

Comment: In the .nsi the "OutFile" instruction sets the name (and optional path) of the generated installer.

Comment: It is not getting generated. Maybe it's because I am not starting the .nsi file, only compiling it? How can I compile and start using the command line? Can't find it on google.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS.exe is not the compiler, MakeNSIS.exe is! The Stubs, Plugins and Include directories are also required and probably the Contribs directory as well.

Comment: I know about makensis.exe. I renamed it to nsis.exe for the sake of clarity. All directories are intact.

Comment: @Dovile: NSIS already has another thing called NSIS.exe, I would not call that clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but i have one of possible solution for this.
If you write app in C# (WinForm, WPF etc.) you can use this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    //Path to makensis.exe
                    FileName = "C:\\NSIS\\makensis.exe",
                    //make the window Hidden
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    //Source to your nsis script
                    Arguments = "D:\\Script\\myapp.nsi"
                };
                try
                {
                    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    // handle exception
                }
```

In many cases this is a universal solution for me.